# Exercise of integration

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have to solve this:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-nt}-(1-t)^n}{t}dt
$$
(hint: $1-e^{nt}(1-t)^n=\int_0^t ne^{\tau n}\tau(1-\tau)^{n-1}d\tau$).

I wrote that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-nt}-(1-t)^n}{t}dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1-e^{nt}(1-t)^n}{e^{nt}\,t}dt
$$
and then I tried to use the hint but I don't know how to use it in a good way. I think this exercise should be resolved using the dominated convergence theorem, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=nt$ then
$$\int_0^1\frac{e^{-nt}-(1-t)^n}{t}dt=\int_0^n \frac{e^{-x}-\left(1-\frac x n\right)^n}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-\left(1-\frac x n\right)^n}{x}\chi_{(0,n)}(x) dx$$

Now we have $(1-x/n)^n\ge 1-x$ so
$$\frac{e^{-x}-\left(1-\frac x n\right)^n}{x}\le 1\quad \forall x\in(0,1)$$
and we have clearly
$$\frac{e^{-x}-\left(1-\frac x n\right)^n}{x}\le e^{-x}\quad \forall x\ge1$$
hence by the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1\frac{e^{-nt}-(1-t)^n}{t}dt=0$$

Comment: So the hint given is useless?

Comment: I don't think so but I found my answer straightforward.

Comment: Agreed, that's **much** nicer than following the hint.